# Laravel livewire render not working RateYo plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-livewire, rateyo

I'm using jQuery RateYo plugin for showing star ratings on my product card. First time when the page loads it work perfectly, But when I sort value by Livewire it will not showing star rating. In my livewire component render method I use this

```
$this->dispatchBrowserEvent('contentChanged');
```

And into my blade I try this

```
window.addEventListener('contentChanged', (e) => {      
for (let index = 1; index <= 5; index++) {
    $(".rating_" + index).rateYo({
        rating: index,
        normalFill: "#CCC",
        ratedFill: "#FFC700",
        spacing: "5px",
        fullStar: true,
        starWidth: "16px"
    });
}
```

});
But it's not working. Can anyone tell me how to show rating properly after livewire component render?

I tried to dispaly card with rating without page load by Livewire. But it's not working. It only work when page is reload.